# how to set the nginx root path to a direcoty outside the ngnix dir

Tags: nginx

How would one set the root path of an nginx server to a direcoty outside the ngnix folder?

Currently ngnix is here:
c:/ngnix

I would like c:/www to be the root.

currently with 
    server 
    {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

```
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    root  c:/www;
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
```

Comment: You already have exactly what you want in the piece of config you have pasted there. The only case it won't use c:/www is when the URI /50x.html is triggered as you overwrite the root there.

Answer (score 1):

The `root` option could be inside the `location` block. Try:

```
    location / {
        root   c:/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry this is not true. Directives should whenever possible be placed in the highest possible context as they inherit down. If placed in location / it is *only* available in location / not in any other locations.

Comment: I was referring to his specific example. In fact, this is the syntax in the example `nginx.conf` file – I only modified the `root` line. But you are correct in that his original config works (I tested it just now).

Comment: In this specific example it makes no sense either. The example nginx.conf file provided with the source install is actually a really bad example and the examples on the nginx wiki should be followed instead.

Comment: Interesting – I had no idea! That is good to know, and I'm glad it was captured here as well for posterity. Thanks.